# How to replace in vim

Tags: vim

I have a line in a source file: `[12 13 15]`. In vim, I type:

```
:%s/\([0-90-9]\) /\0, /g
```

wanting to add a coma after 12 and 13. It works, but not quite, as it inserts an extraspace `[12 , 13 , 15]`.

How can I achieve the desired effect?

Comment: `[0-90-9]` doesn't match two digits; it means the same as `[0-9]`.

Comment: @sidyll  I noticed that too, but see your comment too late. I posted it as an answer... :(

Comment: @Kent no worries, please, and +1 for expanding on this idea. It's uncertain though if the substitution wanted contains a comma after the space…

Comment: Thanks for the great responses and hints, I learned 2 new things about vim replacing;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\1` in the replacement expression, not `\0`.

`\1` is the text captured by the first `\(...\)`. If there were any more pairs of escaped parens in your pattern, `\2` would match the text capture between the pair starting at the second `\(`, `\3` at the third `\(`, and so on.

`\0` is the entire text matched by the whole pattern, whether in parentheses or not. In your case this includes the space at the end of your pattern.

Also note that `[0-90-9]` is the same as `[0-9]`: each `[...]` collection matches just one character. It happens to work anyway, because in your data ‘a digit followed by a space’ matches in the same places as ‘2 digits followed by a space’. (If you actually needed to only insert commas after 2 digits, you could write `[0-9][0-9]`.)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about \x syntax?

Comment: Why the command for a line like "[12 1 15]" doesn't match the "1"?

Comment: What do you mean? Which command do you now have, what output are you getting, and what output would you like?

Answer (score 2):

> "I have a line in a source file:..."

then you type `:%s/...` this will do the substitution on all lines, if it matched. or that is the single line in your file?

If it is the single line, you don't have to group, or `[0-9]`, just `:%s/ \+/,/g` will do the job.

Comment: I restricted my problem to this, in my file I have a bunch of similar lines.

Comment: @gg.kaspersky if your :%s/... worked, that line in my post should work too. try it.

Comment: Oh, there is no doubt it works, I wanted to match only the specific spaces after 2 digit numbers.

Comment: @gg.kaspersky yes. and all spaces in your file are those kind of spaces, aren't they? ^_^

Comment: Not really, it is a python source file. Those lines are about a large data definition.

Answer (score 0):

The fine answers already point  interesting solutions, but here's another one,
making use of the `\zs`, which marks the start of the match. In this pattern:

```
/[0-9]\zs /
```

The searched text  is `/[0-9] /`, but  only the space counts as  a match. Note
that you can use the class `\d`  to simplify the digit character class, so the
following command shall work for your needs:

```
:s/\d\d\zs /, /g  ; matches only the space, replace by `, '
```

You said you have multiple lines and  these changes are only to certain lines.
You can either  visually select the lines  to be changed or  use the `:global`
command, which searches for lines matching  a pattern and applies a command to
them. Now you'd need  to build an expression to match the  lines to be changed
in a  less precise  as possible way.  If the lines  that begins  with optional
spaces, a  `[` and two digits  are the only lines  to be matched and  no other
ones, then this would work for you:

```
:g/\s*[\d\d/s/\d\d\zs /, /g
```

Check   the  help   for   [*pattern.txt*](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html)  for   `\ze`   and  similar   and
[`:global`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#%3aglobal).

---

*Homework: use the help to understand `\zs` and see how this works:*

```
:s/\d\d\zs\ze /,/g
```